# R spplot error: invalid 'nrow' value (too large or NA)

Tags: r, r-sp

I am trying to plot 4 point shapefiles. They are close to identical: each is a SpatialPointsDataFrame, each with:

```
CR="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"
```

each with 4 variables. The first has 312 points, the second 337, the third 948, and the fourth 345 obs. I can plot each of them, individually or in one map, using R's simple `plot()` function.

However, when I go to plot them according to a variable value, using `spplot`, the first two plot perfectly, and the second two give me this error:

> Error in matrix(0, rows.per.page, cols.per.page) :
>
> invalid 'nrow' value (too large or NA)

I don't know what this means. I saw one forum response on the subject which pointed towards an error in the CRS. But I know it's not the CRS, as I made these shapefiles w/ identical CRS strings.

Thanks so much in advance for any insights!

Comment: Cross-posted as https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/304824/115